# In C, sort array of strings by string length

Tags: c, arrays, string-length

So I input strings into an array `mydata[10][81]`

```
while ((ct<=10) && gets(mydata[ct]) != NULL && (mydata[ct++][0] != '\0'))
```

I then use a for loop to create a second array of pointers

```
for (i=0;i<11;i++){
    ptstr[i] = mydata[i];
}
```

This is where I get stuck
I know I need to use `strlen` somehow, but I can't even conceive of how to get the length of a pointer and then re-assign that pointer a new position based on a third additional value of length

Hopefully that makes sense, I'm so lost on how to do it or explain it, I'm just trying to sort strings by length using array positions (not using something like `qsort`)

I did some more work on it and came up with this:
any idea why its not working?

```
void orderLength(char *ptstr[], int num){
int temp;
char *tempptr;
int lengthArray[10];
int length = num;
int step, i, j, u;
for (i=0; i<num;i++){
    lengthArray[i] = strlen(ptstr[i]);
}
for (step=0; step < length; step++){
    for(j = step+1; j < step; j++){
          if (lengthArray[j] < lengthArray[step]){
              temp = lengthArray[j];
              lengthArray[j] = lengthArray[step];
              lengthArray[step] =temp;
              tempptr=ptstr[j];
              ptstr[j]=ptstr[step];

              }
          }
    }
    for (u=0; u<num; u++){
        printf("%s \n", ptstr[u]);
        }    
}
```

Comment: Use `qsort` and a custom comparator based on `strlen`.

Comment: You might want to read about the [`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) library function. Or read more about [sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

Comment: How are you planning to do the sort? With quicksort (then follow the other comment's advice) or code your own? And that while loop is awful - easy to corrupt memory by reading too long a string AND by reading too many strings... And your for loop goes one off the end of the ct array as well! (assumiing you meant mydata, not mystrings)

Comment: Hint: if you were just sorting the strings, you'd call `strcmp` to compare the contents. If you're sorting them by length, you compare the lengths instead (compare the values returned by `strlen`)

Comment: OP declared `mystrings[10][81]` but then `for (i=0;i<11;i++) ptstr[i] = mystrings[i];` which will exceed the array bounds. Change to `for (i=0;i<10;i++)`. I *strongly* advise on the use of `#define` to set array and other sizes, i.e. don't "hard code" every individual statement. One upshot is you can alter the limit / size if necessary in one stroke.

Comment: Don't use [`gets()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/315052).

Comment: Okay so it sounds like ill use the strcmp incorperated in a sort algorithm, but how do i feed things into the strcmp would it be something like strcmp(strlen(*ptstr[i]),strlen(*ptstr[i+1])) where im getting the value that ptstr points to and comparing it

Comment: @Knell: No, no, no! `strlen` is for comparing strings. `strlen` yields numbers. There is no standard function for comparing numbers, but look at Nit's answer bbewlo, which implements a suitable comparison function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As suggested in the comments by [Deduplicator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3204551/deduplicator), you can use `qsort` defined in `stdlib.h`.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROWS 4
#define MAXLEN 20

int compare (const void * a, const void * b) {
    size_t fa = strlen((const char *)a);
    size_t fb = strlen((const char *)b);
    return (fa > fb) - (fa < fb);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char arr[ROWS][MAXLEN] = {
        "abcd",
        "ab",
        "abcdefgh",
        "abc"
    };
    qsort(arr, ROWS, MAXLEN, compare);
    return 0;
}
```

You can see it in action [over here](https://tio.run/##dVFNa4QwFLznVzxcCnE3W6T0pl3oobd@QHtowUqJMWrAjduY3UOLv90@oy660FzyZjIvmTcRW1FxXXTdSmlRHTMJUWMzVV@XO7KgKpVeckbpoufIKpO50hJeX97f4PYMn@4/Hh@e4SYgRGkLot4fuJFARa0bC6daZbAGzmCBUx9@CeBq1I/8spBzuAN8q5Kajp2i5AbWPvfDhTD9T5iOQiPt0WigeOUO5T5sXR31dUjaweWeK037gptCTN6Gi3rqFCeTQUdyY@J@7CQepk3QxHDcL4@nIvPYHC@RwKiK8oLzHGoH099NbSzFZ5iLl42psilOdO50eW2AjlEoNBGEuEWuB6vNxp/ZOuDP2Zx6V82n9pibQSVjSO08qgBj6bo/).

Comment: I doubt I'd ever use that expression. The intent of it isn't clear.

Comment: I believe I know one possible reason to use `(fa > fb) - (fa < fb)` rather than `fa - fb`, and that would be if the expression `fa - fb` were to result in a numeric underflow or overflow. So in a 32-bit world, suppose `fa` is `2^31 - 1` and `fb` is negative `2^31 - 1` Then `fa - fb` is `2^32 - 2` which is a negative result even though `fa` is greater than `fb`. So I may have to take back what I said about simplifying that `return` expression!

Comment: I just learned something, hadn't seen a return like that before!

Comment: @lurker  `fa`, `fb` cannot be negative.  Their type is some unsigned integer.  `fa - fb` is never negative as long as `SIZE_MAX > INT_MAX`.

Comment: @chux understood. I was thinking of other more general cases which may not be `size_t` based. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @lurker As your "Minor tweak:" comment received 2 up-votes, you may want to delete it especially if it gets another up-vote.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid to call several time strlen() on the same strings, you can use a listed chain of structures like following :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct  t_elem
{
    char        data[81];
    int         length;
    t_elem      *next;
};

int     main(int ac, char **av)
{   
    t_elem      *head;
    t_elem      *recent;
    t_elem      *current;

    while (/* string have to be sorted */)
    {
        if (head == NULL) {
            head = (t_elem *)malloc(sizeof(t_elem));
            head->data = //readTheFirstString();
            head->length = strlen(head->data);
            head->next = NULL;
        }
        else {
            recent = (t_elem *)malloc(sizeof(t_elem));
            recent->data = //readTheNextString();
            recent->length = strlen(recent->data);
            recent->next = NULL;

            if (recent->length < head->length) {
                recent->next = head;
                head = recent;
            }
            else {
                current = head;
                while (current->next && current->next->length < recent->length) {
                    current = current->next;
                }
                recent->next = current->next;
                current->next = recent;
            }
        }
    }

    // print the sorted chained list
    current = head;
    while (current->next) {
        printf("%s\n", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }

    // free the list
    current = head;
    while (current->next) {
        recent = current;
        current = current->next;
        free(recent);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A really simple version might look like this. It's a [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) which is pretty slow for any reasonable size data but it looks like you're only sorting 11 elements so it won't matter here.

The key is the 'if' statement which compares the lengths of the two array positions. The next three lines swap them if they were out of order.

```
char* temp;
int length = 11;
int step, i;
for(step = 0; step < length - 1; step++)
    for(i = 0; i < length - step - 1; i++)
    {
        if(strlen(ptstr[i]) > strlen(ptstr[i+1]))
        {
            temp = ptstr[i];
            ptstr[i] = ptstr[i + 1];
            ptstr[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
```

Edit:
If you want to sort by the contents of the string not the length then change the if statement to:

```
if(strcmp(ptstr[i], ptstr[i + 1]) > 0)
```

(note: you're better off using str**n**cmp where possible)

Comment: `if(strcmp(ptstr[i], ptstr[i + 1]))` would be a bit pointless: swapping strings every time the strings are not the same.  Maybe you meant `if(strcmp(ptstr[i], ptstr[i + 1]) > 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
//C program to sort string based on string length.
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char a[200][200],temp[20];
    int i,j,n;
    printf("Enter no. of strings to be input = ");scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter %d strings:\n",n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%s",&a[i]);
//Sorting string based on length
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n-i-1;j++)
        {
            if(strlen(a[j])>strlen(a[j+1]))
            {
                strcpy(temp,a[j]);
                strcpy(a[j],a[j+1]);
                strcpy(a[j+1],temp);
            }
        }
    }
    printf("After Sorting :\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    printf("%s\n",a[i]);
    return 0;
}
//Made By Capricious Coder; Happy Coding :D
```