# Sort String Array by String Length in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have an array of strings in C. These strings store the paths of filesystems that need to be unmounted.

```
For example...
mountlist[0] = "/proc"
mountlist[1] = "/dev"
mountlist[2] = "/dev/shm"
and so on...
```

I need to unmount the nested filesystems before the filesystems they are mounted over (so `/dev/shm` needs to be unmounted before `/dev`). I was thinking that the easiest way to do this would be to sort the strings by length, longest first. I have the number of strings in the array stored in the integer `i`.

With the code that I've been able to come up with so far, given that `strnum` is an integer of the string I need to access, the strings are accessible with `mountlist[strnum]` and the corresponding length is stored in `length[strnum]`.

In conclusion, how can I sort the strings in array by greatest to least length? I don't need to actually sort the strings, I just need to access them in the right order. I can't figure out how to write it, but I was thinking of code that creates an int array with the number of each string array in the right order (the example above would be {2, 0, 1}), so if that array was named `sort` then `mountlist[sort[0]]` would be the longest string. With such an array, the corresponding `for` loop would be:

```
for (int q = 0; q < i; q++) {
    umount(mountlist[sort[q]]);
}
```

Comment: do you know about `qsort()`?

Comment: @Fureeish No, I'll look it up.

Comment: If the order is based on the length it may fail. Example: if you have `"/dev/shm"` and `"/somenonnested"`, latter will be unmounted before `"/dev/shm"` because it's length is longer...

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/27003340/4288486 ?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Good point. I'll probably leave `/dev` in tact, now that I think about it.

Comment: You should probably take into account the number of `/` characters rather than the string length. But the sorting problems itself remains the same. If you have more than 2  nesting levels you may need to build a tree and unmount the leaves bottum up.

Comment: Usually, sorting the names in reverse order gives you the result you require.

Comment: `"/path"` will always be lexicographically less than `"/path/contained"` where `/path` is a directory, and `contained` is something in that directory.   So it is not necessary to sort by string length - sorting in reverse-lexicographical order will be sufficient

Comment: Can you record the path names in the array in the sequence of mounting, and then unmount in reverse order?

Comment: @WeatherVane No, this program is only responsible for unmounting, not mounting.

Comment: @jabberwocky: if you have `/foo/bar`, `/foo` and `/unrelatedlongname`, why would it be a problem if the last one were unmounted first? The only order dependence is between the first two.

Comment: @rici I think that @jabberwocky was pointing out that certain long paths are probably dependent on `/dev` (i.e. block devices), but I decided not to unmount `/dev` so you're right, it won't be a problem.

Comment: @billy: although I wouldn't recommend unmounting `/dev`, there is no dependency. Devices don't exist because they are in `/dev`. The devices are there, regardless. `/dev` lets you refer to them, nothing more.

Comment: @rici Good to know. I always wondered about that, since `/` can't be unmounted I thought that must have meant that `/dev` couldn't have been either.

Comment: @billy: actually you can unmount the filesystem mounted on `/`, but that doesn't make `/` go away. If you were to unmount `/dev`, you'd probably find that there still is a `/dev`, which will be an ordinary (and probably empty) directory in the root filesystem.

Comment: Of course, to unmount the root filesystem, you'd first have to make sure no process was using it. That would be tricky. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `qsort` with a custom comparator:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int cmp(const void *first, const void *second) { 
    const char **firstCast = (const char ** )first;
    const char **secondCast = (const char **) second;
    return strcmp(*secondCast, *firstCast);
}
int main(void) {
    const char *a[3];
    a[0] = "longest";
    a[1] = "short";
    a[2] = "medium";
    qsort(a, 3, sizeof(char *), cmp);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: He wants the sorting based on string lengths (which may not be the right choice btw, see my comment to the question), not based on string comparision.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to depend on anything "external" like qsort, which may or not be available in your environment, this should do it:

```
for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) sort[j] = j;

for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; ++j) {
    int longest = j;
    for (int k = j + 1; k < i; ++k) {
        if (length[sort[k]] > length[sort[longest]]) longest = k;
    }
    int tmp = sort[longest];
    sort[longest] = sort[j];
    sort[j] = tmp;
}
```

Comment: qsort is included in the [C standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.5.2) so there is no question about it being available.